# How can I pass different types of list<T> into a method for grouping by similar fields

Tags: c#, linq

**I would like to create a generic method that will accept lists of different types with similar fields that I can group by.**

For instance, I have two lists:

```
 - List<MemberPurchases> Purchases 
 - List<MemberReturns> Returns
```

I want a method that will accept both of the different types of lists and then group them by a similar field: (Purchases.MemberID or Returns.MemberID).

**Here is what I have, but it won't let me do any linq queries on the list when passed in:**

```
Public static int GetMemberActivity<T>(List<T> memberList)
{
    var groupedList = memberList.GroupBy(x => x.  
}
```

At that point I only get four options (which none of them are the elements in the list):

1. Equals
2. GetHashCode
3. GetType
4. ToString

**What I'm looking for is:**

```
var groupedList = memberList.GroupBy(x => x.MemberID);
```

How can I fix this so I can pass in any list that has the MemberID element and group by it via LINQ.

Comment: do `MemberPurchases` and `MemberReturns` inherit from a same class that have MemberID property ?

Comment: no, they don't.  They're auto-generated Partial Classes being used as DBSet types by Entity Framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about defining an interface, with the similar property in it, which your classes can then implement:

```
public interface IMember
{
    int MemberID { get; set; }
}

public class MemberPurchases : IMember
{
    public int MemberID { get; set; }

    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
}

public class MemberReturns : IMember
{
    public int MemberID { get; set; }

    public string AnotherProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Then use that interface in your method:

```
public static int GetMemberActivity(List<IMember> memberList)
{
    var groupedList = memberList.GroupBy(x => x.MemberID);

    return groupedList.Count();  // I'm just guessing what you want to return here
}
```

Cast your list to the interface, then pass it to the method:

```
var result = GetMemberActivity(Purchases.ToList<IMember>());
```

Comment: That is a really great idea, and I'll use it for some of my other code instead of passing dynamics.  However for this problem the List Types

    <MemberPurchase> and <MemberReturns>

are auto-generated Partial Classes used as DBSets in Entity Framework.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a common interface, and accept a strongly typed List of that common interface.

```
public interface IMember
{
    int MemberID { get; set; }
}
public class MemberPurchases : IMember
{
    public int MemberID { get; set; }
    //...
}
public class MemberReturn : IMember
{
    public int MemberID { get; set; }
    //...
}
```

So you can have:

```
public static int GetMemberActivity(List<IMember> memberList)
{
    var groupedList = memberList.GroupBy(x => x.MemberID);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

(1) Several possible approaches, flexible, **but type-safety not enforced**:

1. Extract value of MemberID [using reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194385.aspx).
2. Check the type of passed object (e.g. using `is` or `as` statement), cast the generic object to correct type, then access the property directly.
3. Use [GroupBy method in ObjectQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359331.aspx) that has string parameter for grouping keys. Of course you need to change your method parameter type from List to another type.

(2) **Recommended type-safe way** --> define a new interface to get MemberID value, then apply it to MemberPurchases and MemberReturns. As those classes are generated by EF as partial, you can create a new partial class **file** with same name, then implement the interface. (partial class means that a class **can have multiple source-file to describe a single same class**, so you can extend the class directly). Here's an code example in newly created `.cs` file:

```
public interface IMember
{
    object MemberGenericID{get;}
}

public partial class MemberPurchases : IMember
{
    object IMember.MemberGenericID
    {
        get { return MemberID; }
    }
}

public partial class MemberReturns : IMember
{
    object IMember.MemberGenericID
    {
        get { return MemberID; }
    }   
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
    void Group(List<IMember> list)
    {
        list.GroupBy(x => x.MemberGenericID)
    }
```